# How to have 3 type of users in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a Django powered website in which i have three types of users:

- Teachers: can add training stage offers,
- Students: can apply for a training stage offer,
- Companies: can also add training stage offers.

My **main question** is how to have three types of users in Django, so that I can have three types of login?

My current solution is that I have three models of each type of user (Model Student, model Teacher, model Company). I also have three types of different forms to allow companies, teachers or students to register. When a form is correctly compiled in my view I create manually(by coding), a user and I manually create a object for the relative model then save that object.

The main problem is that the user I create is not differentiated by there type:

```
class Azienda(models.Model):
nome=models.CharField(max_length=200)
sede=models.CharField(max_length=200)
pIva=models.CharField(max_length=30)
email = models.EmailField()
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
#company model, in models.py

#company form, in forms.py
class AziendaForm(forms.Form):
nome = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
sede = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
pIva = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
email = forms.EmailField()
user = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

#view of company registration form
def registratiAziende(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form=AziendaForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form['nome'].value()
        azienda=Azienda()
        azienda.nome=form['nome'].value()
        azienda.sede = form['sede'].value()
        azienda.pIva = form['pIva'].value()
        azienda.email=form['email'].value()
        #I create a user         user=User.objects.create_user(form['user'].value(),form['email'].value(),form['password'].value())
        azienda.user=user
        azienda.save()
        #I save the company object
    return redirect('myapp:index')
else:
    form= AziendaForm()

return render(request, 'myapp/registratiAziende.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Create a single form for a user and add a new field for the role of the user, based on which you can make a new entry in either Teacher, Student or Company. Or, you can extend the Django's default `User` model to add a new field `role` in it, through which you can differentiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three type of user contain similar attribute but different role in your system.

Just add attribute `role` in your model so that you won't need to maintain three models。

Comment: Actually I have some common attributes  in my 3 models, but there are still exclusives attributes.

Comment: You may define those common attributes in model `User` and define `Teachers\Students\Companies` inherit from `User` .

Answer (score 0):

Default User model can be extended by adding this model as a OneToOne field to the default user model. However for your case you have to create a different model as a custom user model by using OneToOneField then use this model in student and teacher and company.

```
CHOICES = (('student', 'student'), ('teacher', 'teacher'), ('company', 'company'))
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CHOICES)
```

Then you can use this model in your Company, Student, Teacher model.

One advice would be not to use common fields for different models. Normalise your db to remove redundancy.

Comment: Actually I have some common attributes  in my 3 models, but there are still exclusives attributes.